# Sveltekit is not reactive when navigating through slug page

Tags: sveltekit

When I navigate through [slug] pages, the content does not update although +page.server.ts is correctly called.

I understand this is an [expected behavior](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4895) and that the solution is to use "$:" to listen to change and reevaluate the statement, but this does not work.

Any idea ?

**+page.server.ts**

```js
import { getPage } from '$lib/services/pages';
export async function load({params}) {
    const page = await getPage(params.slug)
    return { page };
}
```

**+page.svelte**

```js
<script>
    import Editor from '$lib/editor/index.svelte'
    export let data;
    // This is the solution found on similar question but this does not work
    $: content = data.page.text
    // But this works 
    $: console.log(data.page.text)

</script>

<Editor {content}></Editor>
```

Note: Navigation is made with simple  tag on +layout.svelte

EDIT: the Editor component is actually a copy of [this tiptap svelte example](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/demos/src/Examples/Default/Svelte/index.svelte) except the content is passed through the parent.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a similar error in the `Editor` component.
Some things you can try

add the following, it will make a dump of your text on screen and should change

```html
<pre>{JSON.stringify(content, null, 2)}</pre>
```

force the `Editor` component to remount by using `#key`, this likely works but it might be better to fix the component itself depending on your needs.

```html
{#key content}
  <Editor {content} />
{/key}
```

Comment: Thanks. {#key content} works but it doesn't feel right, does it ? I also tried the "$:" thing in my component but it didn't work. My component is actually copy of [this tiptap svelte example](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/demos/src/Examples/Default/Svelte/index.svelte) except the content is passed by the parent.

Comment: the tiptap example you link set the content in `onMount` which doesn't run again, you can probably make this better with reactivity, or use the key trick, it will reset everything (like bold button etc) back to default which you likely actually want

Comment: Indeed, the "issue" seems to be related with the `onMount` hook in my component. I'm trying to mix  `beforeNavigate` (instead of onMount) and Tiptap but the result is currently odd (editor does not reset the text but add it to the previous text on navigation change).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but I recently had a similar/same problem. The trick seems to be to add parentheses. Like this:

```
 $: (content = data.page.text)
```